# HAProxy cannot bind to socket 1883

Tags: linux, sockets, haproxy, mqtt

I am trying to bind a HaProxy on a Fedora 21 instance to socket 1883 (for the MQTT protocol).

I get

```
[ALERT] 215/130943 (926) : Starting proxy mqtt: cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:1883]
```

There does not seem to be anything listening on this port as long as I could check. Does anyone have an idea about what might be the problem?

Comment: It is unfortunate that HaProxy does not log the error returned by `bind()`. Would it be possible for you to run it under `strace` in order to obtain that information?

Comment: Wll... its a very big output. I do not know what to look at. I just realised however that if I run haproxy straight I do not get the bind problem. It is only if I run it as a service and then check 'service haproxy status' that it seems to not work.

Comment: Could it be that another service binds to port `1883` before HaProxy tries to do the same thing, only to relinquish it a few seconds later?

Comment: How do I check for that?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any silver bullet for that. Analyzing your system's booting routine will probably provide the answer, but you will have to go through quite a lot of configuration files (unless you manage to run `netstat` at the appropriate point in the boot process).

Comment: You can probably change your haproxy execution point to run under strace & find something helpful.